# Oracle Application Express 32k limit - workaround

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am trying to insert 1000,000 rows into a table in Oracle APEX but there is a 32k limit and I can only insert 4000 rows at a time. Is there a way to get round this limit. Otherwise I'm gonna be doing inserts for the rest of my life.

Cheers 
Brian

example script

```
INSERT ALL
INTO staff (staffid, forename, familyName, jobRole) values (staffid_auto_incr.nextval, 'Raymond', 'Mccoy', 'manager')
INTO staff (staffid, forename, familyName, jobRole) values (staffid_auto_incr.nextval, 'Janice', 'Cunningham', 'admin')
INTO staff (staffid, forename, familyName, jobRole) values (staffid_auto_incr.nextval, 'Christine', 'Reyes', 'sales')
etc.etc.
select * from dual
```

Comment: I've removed the apex tag and replaced it with *oracle-apex*. I'm not sure what part of the *not to be confused with Oracle Apex* was unclear in the *Apex* tag description, but please read more carefully in the future. Tags have relevance here, and it's important to use only those that actually apply to your question. Also, `1000000 / 4000 = 250`, and given the speed at which computers process data you appear to think you're going to have an extremely short lifespan. In fact, are you still around to read this comment?

Comment: Where is this data coming from?  And why are you writing explicit `insert` statements?  A million rows implies that the data is either in a file, which you can load via `SQL*Loader` or via an external table or from another database, in which case you can write an `insert ... select`.

Comment: wow thanks Ken you really helped me here, you sound like a nice chap.. Anyway I'm a student learning oracle and the data is coming from a text file which I created using a online random data genrator, I'm learning about optimisation, I will look into sql-loader now, cheers

Comment: which 32k limit are you referring to? the varchar2 type maximum length or the maximum plsql script size stored on apex?

Comment: the plsql script size (I think) I wrote the above script and tried to run it but it says the script is too big.

Comment: you should listen to @JustinCave, there's no need for storing a script to insert static values, just copy that into a console and run it.

Comment: thanks for the help, my tutor said just use 50,000 rows, so I've done 12 inserts of 4000 rows